# rsync with 'files from' in wildcards

Tags: rsync

[I had to change the example to make it clear that there are subdirectories.]

Let's say I want to recreate a subset of my hierarchy.  for arguments sake, let's say I want to backup files in filelist.conf

```
# cat rsync-list
ab*
bb*
```

and

```
# find .
.
./abc
./abc/file-in-abc
./abd
./abd/file-in-abd
./aca
./bba
./bbc
./bca
./rsync-list
```

I would have hoped that

```
rsync -arv --include-from=rsync-list --exclude='*' . /somewhere-else
```

would recreate abc, abd, bba, and bbc.  the problem is that it does not descend into the ab* directories, so it does not do abc/file-in-abc and abd/file-in-abd.  so, in this sense, the ab* is not really a wildcard that is expanded into abc and abd and then rsynced.

Comment: `*` doesn't match `/` in shell wildcard expansion either. Use `**` instead.

Comment: two more hints: [1] -vv will explain why patterns make it or not.  [2] to include a subdirectory, its paths need to be included.  e.g., if /etc/logrotate.d/ is in the list, it will be ignored unless /etc is also in the list .

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/rsync.1.html) lists these five options:

```
--exclude=PATTERN       exclude files matching PATTERN
--exclude-from=FILE     read exclude patterns from FILE
--include=PATTERN       don't exclude files matching PATTERN
--include-from=FILE     read include patterns from FILE
--files-from=FILE       read list of source-file names from FILE
```

`--files-from` is for exact filenames, and `--include-from` is for patterns, so you might want to try that instead.

Using `include-from`, you don't *need* to specify `+`, but you do need to exclude everything else. For example, given:

```
$ ls -v1 source
image1.tiff
...
image700.tiff
$ cat includes
image7*.tiff
```

Then I can sync only `image7*.tiff` using:

```
rsync -aP --include-from=includes --exclude='*' source/ target
```

The manpage also says, in the `INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES` section:

> - a ’*’ matches any path component, but it stops at slashes.
> - use ’**’ to match anything, including slashes.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `--include-from` instead of `--files-from` if you want to use wildcards. `filelist.conf` should look like this:

```
+ /usr/lib/ld-* 
+ /usr/bin/gcc*
+ /etc/passwd
+ /etc/nonexisting
- *
```

You need to specify `+` or `-` to include or exclude in the file. The `- *` rule at the end is necessary to make include rules work since everything is included by default. Don't put this first or it overrides the include rules.